# How do I call MVC Controller from with Javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have a onclick event on a submit button in my CI app.  So when user clicks submit, it goes to my js function that disables the button, but it does not continue processing.  I used this “document.forms[“mainFrm”].submit();”, but because of the way the code is written I need it to go directly to a controller and finish processing.

So how do I call a CI controller from my js function?

Here is the function that is being called onClick:

```
function disableWhenSubmit()
{
 alert ("You did get here");
 var holdBtnElement = document.getElementById('btn_Add');
 holdBtnElement.disabled = true;
 holdBtnElement.value = "sending ...";
 //document.forms["createRequestForm"].submit();
 <?= base_url();?>index.php/request"; //this is what I am working on
}
```

and here is the button:

```
input type="submit" id="btn_Add" name="btn_Add" value="Submit">
```

Comment: i think you looking for [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Answer (score 1):

**index.php**

```
<script>
    // create a global var before calling your external
    // javascript file(s).
    var BASE_PATH = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
<script src="link_to_myjavascript.js"></script>
```

**myjavascript.js** (jQuery example)

```
(function($){

    $(function(){

          var do_ajax = function(some_params){
               $.ajax({
                    url : BASE_PATH + 'controller/method',
               });
          }

          if(conditions)
          {
             do_ajax(some_params);
          }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this seems to be working, I just hid the submit button upon click using jquery: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmitJob").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#btnSubmitJob").before("Processing....");
    });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Look at ajax call.
Using prototypejs or Jquery

```
<input type="button" onclick="dosomething()" />
```

example

```
<script>
function dosomething() {
  var url = "something.php";
  new Ajax.Request(url, {
    parameters: {//parameters},
    onSuccess: function(transport){
      // do something when response is good
    },
    onFailure: function (request) {
      // Do something when somehting goes wrong     
    });
}
</script>
```